# Binary Search for a list of objects?

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Discount>` containing around 100000 Discounts Values. Here, Discount is a class, and i have a `List<Product>` which has around 200000 records .

I have a for each which iterates through all the records of `List<Product>`.
For each iteration through products list i take some values from the product item and add it to a wrapper class . This wrapper class also contains a field Discount and for each Product i have to iterate through all the discounts got .

There s the problem to iterate through this products list it takes a lot of time.
What is the best way to make this faster ??

I was thinking of Binary Search but am finding it hard to implement ?

Any suggestion as to how to go about this ?

Answer (score 4):

If you need fast lookup of the discount values, `List` might be the wrong data structure. Consider using something like a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), which is designed especially for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Heinz. It is quite faster when compared to List . Any more ways i can improve on the performance ?

Comment: Can't think of anything at the moment. If you need to wrap all Product items, you won't get around iterating through your `List<Product>`. Since you put the discounts into a `Dictionary`, lookup of these values should be quite fast already.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from Heinzi's suggestion, I would also suggest to have a re-look at the design/implementation that is forcing you to load hundred thousands objects into the memory and do cross-lookup against each other - perhaps you should be implementing this logic at database level to get the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a `Dictionary` instead of a list? Searches will be much faster.